# MongoDB $project to pluck certain property (return it as array)

Tags: mongodb, project

I have a MongoDB collection like this

```
[
  { taskType:1, client:{name:"Moe",...}, ... },
  { taskType:1, client:{name:"Larry",...}, ... },
  { taskType:1, client:{name:"Curly",...}, ... }
]
```

I can run the following `$project` query on it:

```
{$project:{_id:0, client:"$client"}}
```

and I get this result:

```
[
  { client:{name:"Moe",...} },
  { client:{name:"Larry",...} },
  { client:{name:"Curly",...} }
]
```

but I'm actually looking for a result like this:

```
[
  {name:"Moe",...},
  {name:"Larry",...},
  {name:"Curly",...}
]
```

How can I do it (if I can at all)?

Answer (score 8):

You can bring the `client.name` field up to the top level using a `$project` like this:

```js
{$project: {_id: 0, name: "$client.name"}}
```

**MongoDB 3.4 Update**

You can now do this more directly with a [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/#pipe._S_replaceRoot) stage instead of using `$project`:

```
{$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$client'}}
```

Comment: They have a lot more properties then just the name, as indicated by the "..."

Comment: @IvanKoshelew Three years later, but you can now use `$replaceRoot` to handle that by promoting the entire embedded `client` object to the root as shown in the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use **$group** as

```
db.c.aggregate([{$group: {_id:0, result:{$push:"$client"}}}]);
```

Or append a **map** to your original answer:

```
db.c.aggregate([{$project:{_id:0, client:"$client"}}]).map(function(e) {return e.client;});
```

Comment: I'm using C# driver, which can only use either MapReduce or Agregation, and its MapReduce has to have both Map and Reduce functions. No luck so far.

Comment: @Ivan Koshelew, You can use aggregate **$group** as I show above. It only returns one document, and the fields **result** contains what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Starting `Mongo 4.2`, the [`$replaceWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/#pipe._S_replaceWith) aggregation operator can be used to replace a document by another (in our case by a sub-document) as syntaxic sugar for the `$replaceRoot` operator:

```
// { taskType: 1, client: { name: "Moe",   age: 34 }, price: 234 }
// { taskType: 2, client: { name: "Larry", age: 48 }, price: 129 }
db.collection.aggregate({ $replaceWith: "$client" })
// { name: "Moe",   age: 34 }
// { name: "Larry", age: 48 }
```